# Intersecting floor with rays

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following tikz-code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (point) at (0,0);

% draw the arrows.
\foreach \angle in {0,15,...,360}
   \draw[->] (point) -- (\angle:2);


% draw floor
\draw (-3.5,-1) -- (3.5,-1);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Results in this image:

[image]

However, I want the rays to stop if they collide with the floor. I want something like this(please excuse my poor drawing skills):

[image]

How can I implement this?

Comment: Welcome! Do you want the arrow tips to be drawn at the surface in the intersecting case, or do you just want an abrupt stop?

Comment: If possible, I also want the arrow tips to be drawn.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The library `intersections` helps. If an arrow crosses the floor, the number of intersections, saved in macro `\total`, would be one otherwise zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (point) at (0,0);

    % Draw floor
    \draw[name path=floor] (-3.5,-1) -- (3.5,-1);

    % Draw the arrows 
    \foreach \angle in {0,15,...,360} {
      % Name the path for an arrow with full length  
      \path[name path=ray] (point) -- (\angle:2);    
      % Draw the arrow depending on an intersection point
      % with the floor.
      \draw[
        ->,
        name intersections={                         
          of=ray and floor,                          
          total=\total                               
        },
      ]
        \ifnum\total>0
          (point) -- (intersection-1)
        \else
          (point) -- (\angle:2)
        \fi
      ;
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 14):

As an exercise, I've allowed myself to do this interesting drawing with MetaPost.

The `intersectiontimes` binary operator of MetaPost is here relevant: applied to two paths p1 and p2, it returns a pair of numerics (t1, t2). If these two paths intersect, for each i the numeric ti is the (nonnegative) parameter locating the first intersection point upon pi. Otherwise (if there is no intersection) it returns the pair (-1, -1).

```
u = cm; % general unit
path ray, floor ; floor = (-3.5, -1) -- (3.5, -1);
beginfig(1);
  draw floor scaled u ;
  for theta = 0 step 15 until 345:
    ray := origin -- 2dir theta ; 
    t := xpart(ray intersectiontimes floor) ; % t = -1 if no intersection
    if t = -1: drawarrow ray scaled u;
    else: drawarrow origin -- u*point t of ray;
    fi;
  endfor;
endfig;
end.
```

Since I prefer getting PDF versions of my MetaPost pictures, I generally use the MPtoPDF utility to execute their codes: `mptopdf mydrawing.mp`

The result:

[image: rays intersecting with ground or not]

**EDIT** At Thruston's request ;-) and following (not quite to the letter) his example, here is a simplified version of my code, using the `cutafter` macro instead. Of course it yields the same result as before.

```
u = cm; % general unit
path ray, ground; 
ground = (-3.5, -1) -- (3.5, -1); ray = origin -- (2, 0);
beginfig(1);
  draw ground scaled u;
  for theta = 0 step 15 until 345:  
    drawarrow (ray rotated theta cutafter ground) scaled u;
  endfor;
endfig;
end.
```

Comment: You could simplify your loop a bit if you used `cutafter`...

Comment: @Thruston It's done, greatly inspired by your own answer below. I kept to my own units and scaling, though, I find them simpler than rough PostScript coordinates and the use of `left` and `right` pairs.

Answer (score 10):

With apologies to @fpast, here's a rather simpler Metapost version.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
path ray, base ; 
ray  = origin -- right scaled 60;
base = (left -- right) scaled 100 shifted 30 down;
draw base;
for theta = 0 step 15 until 359:
  drawarrow ray rotated theta cutafter base;
endfor;
endfig;
end.
```

The `cutafter` macro from "plain.mp" does all the hard work here.  The trick is to apply the scaling to both paths at the same point in your program.  As a matter of style I prefer to put it into the definition of the paths before I start drawing.

[image]

Comment: No need to apologize for telling the truth. It's simpler indeed but for the PostScript coordinates, which make the code less readable in my opinion. For my information, why is it necessary to scale the paths when they are defined, before drawing them? Your code works quite well if this scaling is done at the moment of the drawing, I've checked (see my post above). Better accuracy?

Comment: By all means stick to numbers instead of `left`, `right` - it's just a matter of style - for me `shifted 10 down` is clearer than `shifted (0,-10)` but perhaps not for you!

Comment: The important thing about scaling is that it's done to both paths at the same point, so that the `cutafter` macro works. It's fine as you have it.  In general I prefer to move as much as possible outside my loops; but I'd doubt that there's much efficiency to gain here.

Comment: Here not much efficiency for sure, but on the whole you clearly have the right of it. Usually I prefer to scale at the last moment for the sake of (my own) readability but I'll keep your remark in mind when I write heavier loops.